# What collection of BoxDecoration's boxShadow property means?

Tags: css, flutter, decoration

There is a propery `boxShadow` in `BoxDecoration`. It can contains more than one item of shadow. So what does each of one means? How many items it can contains? What difference having one, two, three etc items?

Comment: This link might be helpful for you. Simple and straight forward https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-boxshadow-widget/

Comment: You can place multiple shadows. Think of it has having multiple light sources. So you can have a shadow from the top down and another using a different offset and other properties.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take an example of a box on the table, the number of boxShadow items is similar to number of lights approaching to that box, casting shadows.
One item in boxShadow list means only one shadow (like only one light is casting shadow). Two items will allow you to add another shadow from different perspective like two different lights are approaching, casting multiple shadows from different offsets.